# Интересная php задача с классом и циклом

Tags: php, классы, объекты

Помогите решить задачу, пожалуйста с:

Суть в том, что надо создать объект класса и написать такой foreach или for, чтобы вывести числа от 1 до 10. Но в классе ни в коем случае не должны быть массивы или объекты. Вот так

Comment: Можете конкретизировать задачу? В текущем виде годится чуть менее чем всё, т.к. для вывода чисел от 1 до 10 for самодостаточен, а прикрутить сбоку что-нибудь бесполезное проблемы не представляет. Непонятно, в чём трудность и как задача должна вызывать интерес.

Comment: @Мелкий, честно говоря, не пойму, что ещё здесь можно добавить. Жаль, что эта задача не показалась вам интересной, но я относительно недавно начала учить php и никак не могла понять как можно воплотить выше написанную задачу без массива в классе, так то для меня она довольно забавна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант для PHP>=**7.1**:

```
class Bar
{
    public function get_array(int ...$ints): Array
    {
        return $ints;
    }
}

$ob = new Bar;

foreach ($ob->get_array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) as $int) {
    echo "$int ";
}
```

Результат:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

**UPD-1** Можно и проще сгенерировать массив в теле метода:

```
class Bar
{
    public function get_array(): Array
    {
        return range(1, 10);
    }
}

$ob = new Bar;

foreach ($ob->get_array() as $int) {
    echo "$int ";
}
```

---

**UPD-2** По вопросу из комментария "*это можно сделать с помощью итератора?*" я сделал вывод, что задача была в генерации массива с помощью [генератора](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.overview.php):

```
class Bar
{
    public function get_array($start, $limit): Generator
    {
        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}

$ob = new Bar;

foreach ($ob->get_array(1, 10) as $int) {
    echo "$int ";
}
```

Результат:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: хм, а не подскажите, это можно сделать с помощью итератора?

Comment: @Біпач посмотрите тут: [Итераторы объектов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.iterations.php)

Comment: @Біпач дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: генератором я и сама сделала, но спасибо) интересно именно итератором `class myIterator implements Iterator`

Comment: @Біпач если для этой задачи реализовывать интерфейс Iterator, то решение получится громоздкое.